# is it ok to use a lower wattage dc adaptor?

Tags: power-supply, ac

I have a Samsung TV, with the following specifications:  [image]
The AC/DC adapter broke and I need to buy a new one but I haven't found any adapter with 66W, the closest one was 65W. So I want to know:

1 - Is it ok to use a 65W dc once the TV says 66W?
2 - What does it means the "Typical power"?

Comment: An LCD TV will consume more power when you increase the brightness as the LCD backlight will burn brighter. On this TV, at normal brightness, the average the power consumption is around 36 W. 66W or 65W falls within the tolerance of most adapters so the difference is negligible. Do check that the **voltage** and **plug polarity** are the same. Then the adapter will very likely just work. **But no guarantees, if it blows up, it's your own fault** If you want guarantees, get the Samsung replacement part.

Comment: I asked because I haven't found any original replacement part. Most probably I wont buy the "generic" adapter I guess